# Beers for reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

So it seems that we are crossing the 2-million-reviews milestone.

[image: 1,999,993 reviews]

[image: 2,000,000 reviews]

Now, I know that [reviews are not rewarded with rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163814/243054). I would like to suggest that reviewers be rewarded in physical terms to show their value to the Stack Exchange sites!

Beers.

Beers for reviews, that's a pretty fair trade, no? Users over a certain number of reviews [that were agreed with?] could be mailed a case of their favourite brew.

**<s>Minor</s> Complications**

There would be some logistical kinks to be sorted out first.

1. shipping cost
2. shaken beer upon arrival
3. method of indicating favourite brew
4. reviewers with a beer allergy
5. (added by Joe) importing/exporting alcohol
6. (added by Joe) underage users
7. (added by Ben) some reviewers may prefer rum
8. (added by me how) requires personal info of reviewers
9. (added by Brad Larson) drunk reviewers perform worse than they already do
10. (added by Samuel Liew) not everybody drinks beer [similar to #7 above]
11. (added by Samuel Liew) difficulty of shipping

**Solutions**

1. money isn't everything, as always think of the children (of the happy reviewers when the beers arrive!)
2. include a message in the package directing reviewers to let the bottles sit for a while
3. a new profile field that only appears after N/2 reviews, where N is the beer-qualifying threshold of number of reviews completed
4. send them a refrigerator magnet with a picture of a beer instead
5. the free beers could be limited to countries with liquor companies willing to sell gift cards, then SE could simply send the cards
6. using the gift card idea would allow SE to offload the age verification to the actual place of purchase
7. refuted by OGHaza ("everybody drinks beer")
8. outsource the shipping and handling
9. The Ballmer Peak posits that having a certain amount of alcohol in a reviewer's blood is a productive and valuable state
10. See solution for #7
11. See solution for #8

So, what say the people?

**UPDATE** to summarize findings: It appears that the majority of problems can be put into three categories: choice, legality, and effort. However, all but two the complications have solutions!

Comment: How about a badge instead. Oh wait, that is already in place.

Comment: If you bring you're own drinks you could join the weekly close vote event [in this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)... if you had enough rep ...

Comment: Major complications: importing/exporting alcohol. Under age users.

Comment: I don't like much beer; can I have a case of rum instead?

Comment: one more major is personal information which some of us may not want to reveal

Comment: @mehow I'm sure you could opt out of receiving *whatever*, so this isn't an issue.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a feature request?

Comment: The sheer number of downvotes is unexpected. The downvote hover says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". How does that apply to wanting to make sure that people get rewarded?

Comment: @tar Downvotes on meta are different.  It basically means "No, this should not be implemented" if the question is a feature request.  There are other versions depending on the tag, but that one would apply here.

Comment: I swear some of these reviewers are already drunk. You think badges drove some terrible review abuse? Let's see what happens when free booze is in the mix.

Comment: I really think that this idea deserve a commented beer (not possible to send it by mail) ... Pschhh ... here it is !

Comment: @BradLarson we need a/b testing... I will talk with Shog when I see him around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beer as a reward is never a good idea as:

1. Not everybody drinks beer,
2. Shipping physical products have a completely new set of challenges that the SE team might not have the manpower to execute, especially with restrictions to import/export of alcohol to certain countries, etc., and
3. We already have a badge for that (many in fact)

Comment: C'mon now, everybody drinks beer

Comment: @OGHaza - it depends what you define as "beer" ;)

Comment: Stack Exchange has been distributing physical products for ages. I'm surprised you haven't been aware of any of the giveaways, at all.

Comment: Yeah - I live for the physical giveways :-)

Comment: T-shirts are better

Comment: I heard beer giveaway. That's even enough to make me to risk my sanity with mSO.

Comment: Hi @BoltClock, you mean those for SE team and mods? I'm not aware of other physical products.

Comment: Other than the events SE holds for smaller sites, Stack Overflow has also had contests, such as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please) where the prize was a Stack Overflow mug, as well as T-shirt giveaways, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition). There was even an online store where you could buy merchandise, but that has since closed down.

Comment: Some sites have given away T-shirts, torches, mugs, water bottles, pens, USB memory sticks etc as prizes. I especially like the Travel.SE towel!

Answer (score 10):

Beer as a reward (BaaR) is a very bad idea in this case:

1. I, and many others, would have major legal problems if we got caught drinking our rewards
2. Some folks *can* drink but don't want to
3. People in the review queues already seem drunk enough without us encouraging it.